# How to use a variable with innerHTML.replace I.e innerHTML.replace(/var/g, 'var)

Tags: javascript

I get it to work on just replacing one instance with this code:

```
var someString = ['He', 'Test', 'of'];
var x = 0;
for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(''+someString[i]+'', 'text');
}
```

How to get it to replace all the instances? I tried this:

```
/+someString[x]+/g 
/'+someString[x]+'/g
```

since using a normal string, /Test/g would work how to i format it when the string is a variable string.

Comment: why you do not manipulate string in the loop and then reappend it back to the body?

Comment: Yes, was duplicate. First time im trying javascript have no clue what to search for. This is for an android app, and i only need this small snipped in javascript. Thanks for all answers, so many so fast, not used to over in the android part.

Comment: Use `someString.length` rather that hardcoding 2. `someString.length` is actually 3 in this case.

Comment: They are not really related, i just made it like this for the example. In the bigger program it will loop through much more times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
var someString = ['He', 'Test', 'of'];
var x = 0;
for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(new RegExp(someString[i],"g"), 'text');
}
```

Comment: Choosing this answer for the simplicity. Writing this for a webview in an android app where the java script is in a long string and this method requires little formating. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use `new RegExp` to create a regular expression from a string:

```
for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    var re = new RegExp(someString[x], 'g')
    document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(re, 'text');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use new [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

```
var Replace = ['He', 'Test', 'of'];
for (var = 0;i<String.length;i++) {

var search = Replace[i];
var regEx = new RegExp(search, "g");
var replaceMask = 'text';

var result = 'Test He of where Test he of so'.replace(regEx, replaceMask);
document.body.innerHTML = result;
}
```